# Adding a Loading Screen for AppComponent ngoninit

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I have some authentication and other startup services being called on ngoninit for app.component.ts so that the screen remains black before moving to the homepage. I created a loader service that will display a loading page while its active, however I am still seeing the black screen.

As it stands I always see false for showLoader on the loader component

app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.loaderService.showLoader;
    //startupservice calls and auth calls
    this.loaderService.hideLoader;
  }
```

loader.service

```
loaderSubject = new Subject<any>();


constructor(){

}

showLoader(){
    this.loaderSubject.next(true);
}

hideLoader(){
    this.loaderSubject.next(false);
}
```

loader.component

```
 showLoader = false; 

  constructor(private loaderService : LoaderService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loaderService.loaderSubject.subscribe((value) => this.showLoader = value);
  }
```

Comment: It seem odd when i look your code at first glance, showLoader should be true when init and its state change to false after service already done its job. Then first visit will show loader and wait a moment to hide loader.

Comment: On app.component.ts, ensure you are calling the function by using this.loaderService.showLoader(). Currently, it's just a reference. Subject should be converted to observable before subscribing. Few other things, but hopefully this should set you in right direction

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Angular runs `ngOnInit()` on the parent component (app component) first before the child component (loader component) is created. When the loader component is created the `loaderSubject` is already set to `false`.

Your loader component is rendered when `ngAfterViewInit()` is called in the app component. [Checkout this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gcisys).